# Is it true for all values in probability? - Intersection of $2$ sets

Tags: probability

I know that B can have values only from $0$ to $1$ .
If I have this probability: $\text{Pr}(A=a, B \leq 1)$

Is it true to say that: $\text{Pr}(A=a, B \leq 1) = \text{Pr}(A=a)$

It seems trivial but I am not sure.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general if $\mathsf{P}(B)=1$, then $\mathsf{P}(A\cap B)=\mathsf{P}(A)$ for any event $A$. To see this, note that $\mathsf{P}(A\cap B)\le \mathsf{P}(A)$ and $\mathsf{P}(A^c \cup B^c)\le \mathsf{P}(A^c)+\mathsf{P}(B^c)=\mathsf{P}(A^c)$.

Comment: But $A$ and $B$ are random variables that are not independent, does it still hold? ( I mean, A is dependent on B)

Comment: In your case $\{A=a\}$ and $\{B\le 1\}$ are events.

Answer (score -1):

It's always true that $P(X$ and $Y) = P(X) * P(Y|X)$. Here, we know that $P(B<=1) = 1$, so it follows that $P(B<=1|A=a)=1$ as well. Since the second event is guaranteed to occur, $P(A=a$ and $B<=1) = P(A=a)$.

Comment: that's not true if P(X)=0...

Comment: @MatthewTowers: If $P(X)=0$, then no matter what $P(Y|X)$ is, the product on the right hand side is $0$. So the formula says that $P(X\text{ and }Y)=0$. Do you know any instance where $P(X)=0$ but $P(X\text{ and }Y)>0$?

Comment: @MatthewTowers Yes it is - if $P(X)=0$, then $P(X$ and $Y)=0$, which is both mathematically and intuitively the answer.